# Windows Forms Application: How to Check for Empty Textboxes When Submit Button Is Clicked?

Tags: c#, forms, validation, textbox, windows-forms-designer

In my windows forms application, I have a collection of textboxes from textBox1 - textBox20 and a submit button (button1).

When I press click submit button, How do I iterate through all my textboxes to check if any of them have been left empty and then display a Message Box saying that "textbox # ____ cannot be left empty"?

When I click the submit button I also want to display all the data that the user has input into the textbox.

I'm very new to working with windows forms so I needed the help.

Comment: You can add validation to the individual controls https://www.google.com/search?q=c-sharp+windows+forms+textbox+validation&ie=&oe= or loop through them

Comment: Do you think that telling your user: "TextBox1 is empty" is a good usability feature? You should make some effort to help your user understand the problem (Like "FirstName is required", "Address is required" and so on)

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159409(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Based on the fact that you've manually created the textboxes and they're numbered from 1-20, you could do something like:

```
 private void checkTextBoxes(){
    List<string> textValues = new List<string>();
    bool emptyFound = false;
    for(int i=1;i<21;i++){
       TextBox t = this.Controls.Find("TextBox"+i.ToString(),true)[0] as TextBox;
       //use parent control if you have one ex: Panel1.Controls.Find
       if(t.Text.Length==0){
           emptyFound=true;
           break;
       }
       textValues.Add(t.Text);
    }
    if(emptyFound){
        MessageBox.Show("You left a textbox blank");
    }else{
        MessageBox.Show("You entered values:\n"+String.Join("\n",textValues));
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this

```
private void TextBoxEmpty()
    {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        bool emptyTextbox = false;
        for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                TextBox myTextBox = (TextBox)Controls.Find("textBox" + i.ToString(), true)[0];
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(myTextBox.Text))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(myTextBox.Name + " cannot be left empty");
                    emptyTextbox = true;
                    continue;
                }
                result.Append(myTextBox.Text + Environment.NewLine);
            }
            catch
            {
                continue;
            }
        }
        if (!emptyTextbox)
            MessageBox.Show(result.ToString());
    }
```